# Как правильно обявить класс?

Tags: java

Дана структура данных, для которой определен итератор. Она содержит элементы, которые можно сравнивать друг с другом по значению.
Тип такой структуры можно определить как `Iterable<T>`, при этом `T` реализует интерфейс `Comparable<T>`.

Как правильно объявить класс для такой структуры?

Answer (score 2):

```
class Smth <T extends Comparable<T>> implements Iterable<T>
```

Вроде компилируется: http://ideone.com/yKCpLI

Comment: Зачем implements `Comparable<Smth<T>>`? В условии только T comparable

Comment: @Sergey, ой. Я вместо итератора подумал про компаратор в первом предложении. Значит, лишнее.